Need to add partitioned cookie attribute for session cookie set by Tomcat server
I have a web-app-1 that I am loading in an iFrame on a page loaded from web-app-2.
Since the JSESSIONID from web-app-1 becomes a third-party cookie for web-app-2, the browser disbars it and the user is appeard as logged out from web-app-1 requiring a login.
How can I set the "partitioned" attribute on the JSESSIONID cookie generated by the Tomcat.
I have tried capturing the cookie via filter and adding attribute via setAttribute() function, but when the cookie reaches the browser, it doesn't have the desired effect. Under the "Partition Key" column in the Network tab, for the cookie in the request, I don't see a value.
